# Bootable flash drive for ubuntu

Tags: flash

I'm trying to make my usb flash drive to a bootable stick. I've downloaded the ubuntu 16.10 iso and whenever I try to make it with startup disk creator this error occure.
What should I do?

[image: installation error]

Comment: Please tell us: Which version of Ubuntu are you running (where you want to use the Startup Disk Creator)? What pendrive is it? Check if the pendrive is read/write - that you can write to it: See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297 - You can use mkusb both to wipe the first megabyte of the pendrive (a quick check) and to make it a USB boot drive, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: do you have any access to any windows machine(desktop or laptop) if you have than it will be much easier :)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 
usb: Transcend

Comment: @PankajGautam no... :(

Comment: well don't worry i have found a solution

Comment: See the following answers to similar problems - how find out, if your flash drive is good or not - https://askubuntu.com/questions/871607/cannot-get-the-partition-table-on-2-usb-sticks-cleared-after-using-dd/871655#871655  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/871026/unable-to-format-sd-card/871351#871351

Comment: @sphoenix - you can  upvote my answer if it helps you

Comment: did it, but my reputation is low :v

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Note : This assumes that you are on **Linux(Ubuntu)** platform.

To create a USB stick from which you can install Ubuntu, you must first [download Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download) of the flavor you want.

**Then, follow these instructions:**

1. Insert a USB stick with at **least 2GB** of free space.
2. Open the `dash` and search for **Startup Disk Creator**.
3. Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app.

   [image: startup disk creator]
4. Click **Other** to choose the downloaded ISO file if it isn’t found automatically, select the file and click **Open**.

   [image: app screen]
5. Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click **Make Startup Disk** and then **Yes**.

   [image: selecting USB drive]
6. That's it! When the process completes, you'll be ready to **restart** your computer and begin installing Ubuntu.

[image: writing iso image]

Comment: Use the Disks app. This app has known issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/674980/startup-disk-creator-appears-to-be-hanging

Comment: For anyone who doesn't have "startup disk creator" installed, the package name is "usb-creator-gtk"

Answer (score 6):

You can make a bootable Ubuntu stick by running `sudo udevadm monitor` and inserting the usb stick. This will tell you where your usb stick is located in the /dev directory. Then run `dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX` where X is the dev directory node that you saw from the previous command when inserting your usb stick. Then boot it!