# i can't run ubuntu with any nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

i'm using a really old pc right now. when i try to install nvidia drivers for this graphics card (8600m gt) after reboot ubuntu goes for a blinking cursor with black screen. after hours at forums went to root shell deleted and reinstalled 2 reccomended drivers (340 and 304) still boots black screen. only nouveau display drivers boots to ubuntu gnome but it's pretty laggy.

so i'm thinking about this graphics card not working well probably after years but that much? i can't even watch videos at 360p.
my goal is using simple graphic programs and coding until my normal pc fixed

also i did a fan cleaning clean and apply new thermal paste and temperatures are near 55c.

do u have any reccommendation? i'm using ubuntu 16.04

edit:i clean installed 18.04 64-bit it didn't help. after installing nvidia-340 driver now it stuck on a black screen after reboot.

**output of command `mokutil --sb-state`**

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

**output of command `lspci -vnn | grep VGA`**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84M [GeForce 8600M GT] [10de:0407] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

**output of command `lshw -c video`**

```
> -display UNCLAIMED       
>        description: VGA compatible controller
>        product: G84M [GeForce 8600M GT]
>        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>        version: a1
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
>        configuration: latency=0
>        resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**output of command `ls /sys/firmware/efi/`**

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi/': No such file or directory
```

nvidia-340 driver didn't work for me. i tried different versions too.
it just stuck on a black screen after installing any nvidia driver. i used nomodeset when installing ubuntu. 5-6 times reinstalled drivers and os today.

**i also have that output `ubuntu-drivers devices`**

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000407sv00001028sd000001F1bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : G84M [GeForce 8600M GT]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

i think i'm using xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

Comment: What was the previous working version of Nvidia driver for 8600M GT? Please edit your question and post the output of these commands: 1. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/`  2. `mokutil --sb-state` and 3. `lspci -vnn | grep VGA`

Comment: i can't tell which nvidia driver worked before, it was years ago. i just installed ubuntu this pc after years. thanks for reply –

Comment: 18.04 is latest and you are good! Only problem could be that your machine is not configured for EFI. You better prepare a bootable USB stick with `“Partition scheme” to “GPT”` and `"Target system” as “UEFI (non CSM)`. You may use `Rufus` to prepare USB stick. BTW, what was the output of command `ls /sys/firmware/efi/`?

Comment: You may try  [GeForce Nvidia-342 Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/112596/en-us).  If 342 fails, then you try [Nvidia-100 released on 2007-Jun-8](https://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_ia32_100.14.09.html). If you have further questions, please let me know.

Comment: Please give us the output of `lshw -c video` so that we can find out which driver you are using. The `nvidia-340` driver should work for you, according to https://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html

Comment: @Marmayogi i dont have windows installed at this pc so i cant use rufus now

Comment: Please refer this: [How can I change/convert a Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from).  You need not worry about Rufus preperation, now. Nevertheless, you need one in future for troubleshooting. Please post the result of MBR to EFI conversion. Good luck!

Comment: You can preapre bootable USB stick for Ubuntu using `startup disk creator`. Refer [Bootable flash drive for ubuntu using "startup disk creator"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876058/bootable-flash-drive-for-ubuntu). If `startup disk creator` is not installed on your system, then use `usb-creator-gtk` package to install from command line as `sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk`. Or else, use `Ubuntu Software` GUI tool and install `startup disk creator`.

Comment: @Marmayogi i just gave up on this pc after trying to efi conversion. read tons of guides, 0 results. i think i'm gonna use this pc with that lag for a while. thank u for replies! :(

Comment: Please hold your horses! You try to prepare a bootable USB stick for ubuntu using `startup disk creator` and try to install Ubuntu 18.04 afresh. Make sure  that you follow two parameters: 1. `GPT partition scheme` and 2. `UEFI (non CSM`) while preparing bootable USB stick. Please don't give up!

Comment: @Marmayogi so i prepare my usb stick to GPT with gparted then i use startup disk creator with xubuntu 18.04 (i decided to switch to xubuntu for this pc). I think it WORKED! i can see i am using nvidia-340 drivers at additional drivers. videos and programs working smooth. i don't know how to thank u after two days on it Marmayogi!

Comment: I am very very glad that your problem is  resolved! Good Luck!